# WP8 HttpWebRequest Post Not Working

Tags: c#, json, wcf, post, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone Application and I I am trying to post data in JSON format to a WCF application. Although the connection is made, the server returns with a custom message with

This is the C# code:

```
ReportSightingRequest.Instance.Source = Source.IPhone;
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ReportSightingRequest.Instance);
var uri = new Uri("urlGoesHere", UriKind.Absolute);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = jsonData.Length;

string received;
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
{
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the WCF Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[Description("Description.")]
Response.Response ReportSighting(ReportSightingRequest sighting);
```

This is the implementation:

```
public Response ReportSighting(ReportSightingRequest sightingRequest)
{
    var response = new Response();
    if (sightingRequest == null || sightingRequest.TypeId == null)
    {
       response.Status = ResponseStatus.InvalidArguments;
       response.Message = "Request is null or no type has been supplied.";
       return response;
    }
...
}
```

When I call the ReportSighting method form the phone, I get a "Request is null or no type has been supplied" message. The strange thing is that I **AM** sending a `TypeId` and the `sightingRequest` object on the WP8 side is definitely not null when i'm sending it. When I put a breakpoint on the jsonData, it has everything in it. The `ReportSightingRequest` object too is exactly the same as the `ReportSightingRequest` in the WCF application.

It almost feels like that the object isn't being serialized. That's the only thing I can think of.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

**Update**

I've noticed that i'm actually not sending over the object. Shawn Kendrot's Answer seems to make sense but when I integrate his code, it returns with a **Not Found** error.

**Update**
The following code works in a Console App:

```
        var jsonData = "a hard coded JSON string here";
        var uri = new Uri("a url goes here", UriKind.Absolute);
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        webRequest.ContentLength = jsonData.Length;

        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(ar =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var os = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(ar))
                {
                    var postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
                    os.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            webRequest.BeginGetResponse(
                ar2 =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (var response = webRequest.EndGetResponse(ar2))
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            var received = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            //Console.WriteLine(received);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }, null);
        }, null);
```

**Update**
I have changed my code in WP8 to match that of Shawn Kendrot's solution. The problem which I am facing here is that I get a `Not Found` error message:

```
webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(ar =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var os = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(ar))
                    {
                        var postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
                        os.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unsuccessful");
                }

                webRequest.BeginGetResponse(
                    ar2 =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            using (var response = webRequest.EndGetResponse(ar2))
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                var received = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Unsuccessful");
                        }
                    }, null);
            }, null);
```

I get a:

{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MessageBox_ShowCore(String messageBoxText, String caption, UInt32 type)
   at System.Windows.MessageBox.ShowCore(String messageBoxText, String caption, MessageBoxButton button)
   at System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(String messageBoxText)
   at Notify.Logic.WebServices.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_1(IAsyncResult ar2)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_1b(Object state2)}

When I try to do `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

**Update**

I have fixed the issue with the MessageBox.Show error message.

The `webRequest.Headers` object has the following:

`{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8;}`

Comment: It doesn't look like you are sending any data. To send data you need to use the [BeginGetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream(v=vs.90).aspx) method

Comment: Can you please provide a solution or elaborate on how I can change the existing code to get the POST working?

Comment: As it is a WCF service, have you tried adding a service reference to the project and working with the generated class(es)?

Comment: You cannot show a messagebox in the catch. you'll need to write it to the output window: Debug.WriteLine(ex.message)

Comment: Shawn is right, you cannot use a MessageBox here since the catch does not happen in the UI thread.
Could you use Fiddler or WireShark to see the body of your request ? If the body is OK, then the problem might be on the WCF side (deserialization), otherwise it could be a serialization issue.

Also, could you check the HTTP headers of your requests and show them here ? this could be the cause of the issue if serialization/deserialization does not happen.

Comment: I have updated the Original Post. Please check the bottom of it.

Comment: @Subby What is your **final** question after so many *updates*

Comment: I still have the exact same question. The updates show the different methods which I have used and approaches which I have taken. They show what I have tried. The question hasn't changed at all. If you read my updates alongside the comments which Shawn Kendrot has given, you'll understand where I am currently at. Why do I get a -1 for updating and making sure everyone knows where I am at?

Answer (score 3):

Your sightingRequest is null because you are not sending any data. To send data using a WebRequest, you need to use the BeginGetRequestStream method. This method allows you to package the data.

```
var webRequest= (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
webRequest.ContentLength = jsonData.Length;
webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(ar =>
{
    try
    {
        using (Stream os = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(ar))
        {
            var postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
            os.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Do something, exit out, etc.
    }

    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(
        ar2 =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var response = webRequest.EndGetResponse(ar2))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string received = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Do something, exit out, etc.
            }
        }, null);
}, null);
```

Comment: And:  The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Comment: If the service existed before, it should still exist :)
What are you trying to do when it completes? Are you trying to update a UI controls, or some binding? If so, make sure that work is done on the UI thread (Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke).
SIDE NOTE: You may want to use the HttpClient available with the Microsoft.Net.Http Nuget package

Comment: As it is a WCF service, have you tried adding a service reference to the project and working with the generated class(es)? You can add a service reference by right clicking on references and select Add Service Reference

Comment: Hi Shawn! I'm not binding any data and I don't want to use a Service Reference. I want to use the current method using JSON... so Service Reference is out of the question.

Comment: Although the code provided doesn't work for myself, it fixed the issue of "not sending" the data to a server. This question has been cluttered and therefore, i'll open a new one containing a new, up-to-date question since this has been answered by Shawn.